# python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory -Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do a tutorial with tensorflow from Anaconda and created a middle. When installing, you need to install the python "(parking) C:\parking\models\research>python setup.py build" as follows. But it gives an error. Can you help me what should I do?

Comment: Please make sure that the `setup.py` file is present in `C:\parking\models\research`

Comment: There is normally no setup.py in that directory. After compiling the protobufs, I need to run this command "python setup.py build".

Comment: Well you need the file to be that directory...type in the cmd `cd <Path to setup.py>`

Comment: After that give it a try